# c++ socket timeout error when trying to connect

Tags: c++, c, sockets, networking

I've recently into c/c++ socket programming so I just made simple program that server and client respond each other. My server is in VMware( linux fedora) and client is windows(in visual studio 2017).

And it worked(pls notice that server and client are in one laptop)..

I also tried same client code with another computer(my deskTop) and got a WSAETIMEDOUT(10060) 
error. The error was captured in connect() function in client code.

I have no idea how to solve :(

Could anybody help me?

Here's a client code

```
#include <iostream>

#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS
#include <WinSock2.h>

using namespace std;

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN  512

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

   WSADATA wsaData;
   SOCKET connectSocket;
   SOCKADDR_IN servAddr;

   char sendBuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
   char recvBuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

   char nickName[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

   int recvLen = 0;


   if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData) != 0) {
       cout << "start up error";
       exit(1);
   }

   connectSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

   if (connectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
       cout << "socket creation error";
       exit(1);
   }

   memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
   servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);
   servAddr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

   if (connect(connectSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
       cout << "connect error: " << WSAGetLastError();
       exit(1);
   }

   while (1) {

     recvLen = recv(connectSocket, recvBuf, sizeof(recvBuf), 0);
     if (recvLen > 0) {

        if (strcmp(recvBuf, "Exit") == 0)
            break;

        cout << recvBuf;
        //cin >> nickName;
        cin.getline(nickName, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);

        send(connectSocket, nickName, sizeof(nickName),0);
    }
    else if (recvLen == 0)
        cout << "Connection closed";
    else if (recvLen == -1)
        cout << "Connection failed";
}

closesocket(connectSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
```

}

> Blockquote

and server code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define DEFAULT_LEN 512
#define DEFAULT_CLIENT_NUM  30

using namespace std;

char nickNameCommand[]="Please set your nickName:";

void error_handling(char * message);

class Client {

private:
  char nickName[DEFAULT_LEN];
  int clientSock;


public:

   struct sockaddr_in clnt_addr;

   int& getClientSock(){
    return clientSock;
   }


};


class Server {


private:

   int serv_sock;

   char informClientNickName[DEFAULT_LEN] = "Your NickName is ";

public:

   Server(){

 }

 char message[DEFAULT_LEN]= "";
 char clientNickName[DEFAULT_CLIENT_NUM][DEFAULT_LEN];  
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

 void setServSock(int value){
    serv_sock = value;
 }

 int getServSock(){
    return serv_sock;
}

 void setInformClientNickName(int clientNum){
    strcat(informClientNickName,clientNickName[clientNum]);
    strcat(message , informClientNickName);
}

char* getInformClientNickName(){
    return informClientNickName;
}

};


int main(int argc,char * argv[]) 
{

Client clientSocket[DEFAULT_CLIENT_NUM];
Server server;

int clientNum=0;
int recvLen=0;

socklen_t clnt_addr_size;

char message[DEFAULT_LEN];

if(argc!=2)
{
 printf("Usage: %s <port>\n",argv[0]);
 exit(1);
}

server.setServSock(socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0));
if(server.getServSock() == -1)
error_handling("socket() error");

memset(&(server.serv_addr),0,sizeof(server.serv_addr));
server.serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
server.serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);
server.serv_addr.sin_port=htons(atoi(argv[1]));

if(bind(server.getServSock(),(struct sockaddr*)& 
(server.serv_addr),sizeof(server.serv_addr)) ==-1)
    error_handling("bind() error");

if(listen(server.getServSock(),5)==-1)
    error_handling("listen() error");

clnt_addr_size=sizeof(clientSocket[0].clnt_addr);

while(1) {

clientSocket[clientNum].getClientSock() = accept(server.getServSock(), 
(struct sockaddr*)&(clientSocket[clientNum].clnt_addr),&clnt_addr_size);

if(clientSocket[clientNum].getClientSock()==-1)
    error_handling("accept() error");
else{
    write(clientSocket[clientNum].getClientSock(),nickNameCommand,sizeof(nickNameCommand));

    read(clientSocket[clientNum].getClientSock(),(void*)(server.clientNickName[clientNum]),DEFAULT_LEN);
}

    cout << "Received name is : " << server.clientNickName[clientNum]<<endl;


    clientNum++;
    cout << "ClientNum: " << clientNum <<endl;
    recvLen=0;


    for(int i=0;i<clientNum;i++){

    server.setInformClientNickName(i);
    write(clientSocket[clientNum].getClientSock(),server.message,sizeof(server.message));


 }

}

for(int i=0;i<clientNum;i++)
    close(clientSocket[i].getClientSock());

close(server.getServSock());


return 0;
}

void error_handling(char * message)
{
fputs(message,stderr);
fputc('\n',stderr);
exit(1);
}
```

Comment: You appear to be specifying the server port on the command line.  Are you sure the port is visible through the firewall?

Comment: I used port number 8080. By the way, how to check that port is visible through the firewall?

Comment: On linux you can use `sudo iptables -S`: look for something like `tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT` in the output.

Comment: I did but still doesn't work.  And If the port was problem then my client and server that are both in my laptop would've not connected.

Comment: I also tried command: (iptables -A INPUT -s ip-addr -j ACCEPT) to accept my desktop ip but still results same error..

Comment: It's probably got nothing to do with your client's ip address: it's the port that's the issue.  Please check your vendors documentation for `iptables`.  You could also make use of [`netcat`](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/testing-network-services-with-netcat/) to check basic connectivity.